# Orchard CMS: Create Zones in your own shapes/views as per Layout shape?

Tags: themes, orchardcms, orchard-modules

How can one create custom zones in their views so that they may position Widgets within them:

- I'm not talking Local Zones / content item's parts as per @Display.CustomZone and Placement.info,
- nor am I trying to attach custom zones to the Layout shape,

but a method to basically replicate what the Layout shape manages by default,
but within my own shape/view.

I believe the Layout shape uses zoneHolding - so I imagine you would have to inherit from zoneHolding to achieve the above, but that is just hazarding a guess.

Comment: I assume via the 'vote down' the solution is obvious; 'care to explain?'

Answer (score 0):

To have the zones in your layout, you only have to edit your theme's Layout.cshtml:

```
@Display(Model.MyCustomZone)
```

To be able to add widgets to them, Orchard's dashboard must first know of the zones. You can define them in your theme's 'Theme.txt':

```
Name: My Theme Name
Author: ..
Description: ..
Version: ..
Tags: Awesome
Website: http://orchardproject.net
Zones: MyCustomZone, .., .., ..
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to render a layout zone within your shape/view, hope I can understand your question.

To do this, you have to add your zone name to your theme `Theme.txt` as [devqon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3153169/devqon) mentioned, then to render this in any shape you want, simply use this code:

```cs
@Display(WorkContext.Layout.ZoneName)
```

Note: you don't need to render it in your layout if this is not necessary.

Comment: Aha, I think I understand his question wrong. Please note that he also has to edit the theme.txt to actually be able to add the widgets to them in the dashboard :)